An old horror movie about man-eating, underground dwelling creatures, beneath a mansion
As a kid (about 20 years ago) I watched a horror movie about a family (or maybe a couple, not sure) where the man inherited a mansion in the countryside from his passed away uncle I think and they all decided to visit it. 
Beneath the mansion there were cannibalistic creatures who lived in tunnels and were active during summer, the time when the family decided to go there. 
(I remember the uncle's lawyer telling them that the old man loved the mansion, and staying there every time of the year apart from Summer). 
When the family moved in, they soon found that the creatures come and go in the mansion through the tunnels at night to hunt and soon start killing them.
I also remember a scene towards the end of the movie, where the woman and man were hiding in a room or basement and a group of those creatures found the man and started eating him alive (one of them was chewing on his severed leg). 
I vaguely remember that they were hiding under white sheets (not sure if they were lying on one of those hospital beds with wheels).
The woman might have survived at the end.
The movie should be older than 1995-6. I have a feeling it must be a 80s movie. 
I guess that's it. Does it ring any bells?
Edit
Most likely it was some rare B horror movie. When I think about it, I can’t rule out the possibility of being a foreign horror movie, as I watched it on a VHS rental in mid 90s, subbed in my language (I am not a native English speaker).
I can definitely say that the setting of the movie was in a mansion/big house that belonged to a relative of the family.
I remember two night scenes which had rain and thunderstorm in them.
One, somewhere in the beginning of the movie, where some guys were inside of a white caravan in a rainy night, and they heard knocking on the door. When they got out the creatures got them. (possibly dragged them in an underground tunnel).
I want to mention that the creatures were about a meter tall (3-4 ft) and were pale skinned (They looked pretty similar to the creatures on the cover of “Bleeders” ) and they were coming through tunnels beneath the mansion.
The other scene that stuck in my mind was when the man and woman were hiding in the mansion.  It was night and the setting was fairly dark with occasional flashes of lightning from thunderstorm through the windows of the room they were in. The creatures were inside too and were looking for them. 
At some point they found the man and 4-5 of them jumped on him and started eating him alive. I remember a scene where one of the creatures managed to sever one of the guy’s legs and was chewing on it. 
The woman kept still in her hiding place (I believe it was under some white sheets as I mentioned previously) and after some time the creatures cleared the guy’s corpse and left. 
That’s most of what I remember that could be useful to identify the movie. 
I don’t have high hopes for finding the title, but thanks to anyone trying to help. 
P.S. Sorry about the long post.

Is it called the lurking fear.

What about Ghoulies? Your description seems vaguely similar to the first installment of that franchise. See http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089200/

It sounds like Bleeders to me.

If you're still looking, is the movie "The Gate?"

This movie seems to fit your description for the most part, "Don't Be Afraid of the Dark" from 1973. I haven't seen that version of the film so I can't be sure. But I have seen the 2010 remake which fits your description for the most part, which is why I think you're likely talking about the older version of the movie. 

A neurotic housewife named Sally and her business exec husband move into Sally's family house, a spooky two story Victorian mansion. When Sally starts the redecorating along with her pompous decorator she comes across a locked room in the house. After arguing with the handyman who insists she should leave the room locked, she finally gets the key. But once she opens her father's old study and has the bricks from the fireplace removed, strange things begin to happen. Sally begins to see small creatures everywhere, but no one will believe her. Her husband dismisses her as neurotic and her friend thinks Sally may be losing her mind. But things take a deadly serious turn when the decorator trips at the top of the stairs and falls to his death. -IMDb

And

Sally Barnum and her husband Alex inherit an old mansion from Sally's recently deceased grandmother. Shortly after moving in, she discovers a bricked-up fireplace in the basement den, and asks the estate's handyman, Mr. Harris, about it. He tells her that Sally's grandmother had him seal it up after her grandfather died and that it is better to leave it the way it is...Sally soon begins to feel unsettled in the house. One night while sleeping, she is woken by voices whispering her name, and an ashtray mysteriously falls off her bedside cabinet. However, Alex dismisses her concerns and believes she is suffering from nervous tension. -Wikipedia


It sound like The Lurking Fear (1994)
It sounds like to me, as described in this book:

The Wikipedia plot summary:

Ex-con John Martense (Blake Adams) returns to his childhood home of
  Lefferts Corner after serving time for a crime he didn't commit.
  Martense visits family friend Knaggs (Vincent Schiavelli), a mortician
  who has been holding half of a map for him. The map leads to a
  graveyard where Martense's father hid the money from his last heist.
  Arriving at an abandoned church, Martense is confronted by Cathryn
  (Ashley Laurence), a young woman seeking revenge for the murder of her
  sister, and town doctor Dr. Haggis (Jeffrey Combs). This group is
  quickly joined by a trio of criminals who are looking to find the
  money John's father stole from them. What everyone is not aware of are
  the humanoid creatures lurking underneath the holy grounds.


The movie you're looking for is Bleeders (1997), also known as Hemoglobin. 
I stumbled across this post looking for it, and someone on Facebook ended up answering my question, so I figured since I didn't see any posts with the proper answer I'd sign up and reply. 

Thank you for your reply but if you can explain WHY this movie meets the description it would greatly add to your answer.

The movie is Dark Heritage (1989). It was made before Lurking Fear. 
I was looking for it, too. You can get it on Amazon very cheap, which is what I will be doing soon. 

An uncredited adaptation of H.P. Lovecraft's The Lurking Fear.
  After a violent thunderstorm, mutilated bodies are found at a
  Louisiana campground. Investigative reporter Clint Harrison uncovers a
  dark local legend about the reclusive Dansen clan, who may be
  connected to the murders. Determined to dig up the truth, Clint and
  his buddies decide to spend a stormy night in the seemingly abandoned
  Dansen mansion...


Can you add a link like IMDb and its storyline? If you need help, just say so. Thank you for assisting the community, and I hope you enjoy participating.

The general description made me think of the movie C.H.U.D. (1984) which stands for "Cannibalistic Humanoid Underground Dwellers."  I think that movie had the creatures living in the sewer tunnels under a city, though, so probably not the fit you are looking for.

Photographer George Cooper (John Heard) is documenting the lives of subterranean homeless people, a population that has mysteriously dwindled. After receiving information from a reporter, George becomes aware of a conspiracy theory about cannibalistic monsters lurking in the sewers. He teams up with the reporter, a policeman (Christopher Curry) and a priest (Daniel Stern) to fight two battles: one against the cannibals and the other against a corrupt government official.

C.H.U.D. (1984) - IMDB
C.H.U.D. (1984) -Wikipedia

It's been a long time but I don't recall any inherited mansion in the countryside in C.H.U.D..
